# Replacing huge blocks with sed

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I have 2 files that are generated elsewhere. First one is "what to search", and second one is the replacement. Both files are huge, about 2-3mb each.

I need to write a bash script that takes an even bigger file (about 200-300mb) and replaces all occurrences of file1 contents to file2 contents.

Problem is, file1 and file2 can contain any possible characters, including regexp special symbols.

How can I solve this problem using sed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you must use sed for this?

Comment: Is the "what to search" file one long pattern or is it a list of patterns that correspond line-by-line to a list of replacements (rather than one long replacement text)?

Comment: Artelius: Well, I can't load whole file into memory, if there is any other stream-replacing tool I would be glad to know about it.

Dennis: it is 1 big pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at chgrep:

http://www.bmk-it.com/projects/chgrep/

Cheers,

gregx

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't actually need regular expressions, just direct string matching, `sed` is overkill. What you're really looking for is a fixed-string (maybe even binary) stream editor. Unfortunately, I don't know of one... I hate to suggest possibly reinventing a wheel, but you could write something fairly quickly in C that'd do what you want. A rough draft outline:

- read search-file into memory
- create a buffer of the same size as search-file
- read from stdin (or input-file) into buffer.

  - For each character, if it does not match the parallel character from search-file, shift the buffer. To find out how much to shift it by, read until you find a match to the first character of input-file, then check to see if the rest matches, repeating until you've found a partial match to input-file (or gotten to the end of the buffer). When you shift, print all the non-matching characters to stdout (or output-file)
  - If the buffer ever fills up, i.e. totally matches input-file, print replacement-file to stdout (or output-file). Depending on memory vs. speed, you can keep replacement-file in memory or read it from disk each time.

You could also attempt to automatically escape all regex characters from your input file. This could be done with a horribly ugly list of `sed` substitutions, like

```
sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' -e 's@/@\/@' -e 's/\[/\\[/g' ...
```

(make sure you do the `\` one first!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about sed but in Perl you could do (off the top of my head, untested):

```
perl -0777 -pe 'BEGIN{local $/ = undef; open FROM, "<", shift @ARGV; $from = <FROM>; open TO, "<" shift @ARGV; $to = <TO>} s/\Q$from\E/$to/sog' file1 file2 bigger-file > new-bigger-file
```

If you're interesting in trying Perl, I could try testing it for you tomorrow.

But it sucks the entire bigger-file into memory because it ignores line-breaks so that your search text can span multiple lines.  This will meant that it uses quite a lot of memory!

This answer assumes that the search file is one long search string over multiple lines which must be matched in its entirety rather than a number of separate search strings, any of which can be matched.

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought sed was the optimal solution as it does not need to load everything into memory, it operates on streams.

Comment: Well Perl can operate line-by-line just like sed but that isn't useful if you're replacing 2-3mb chunks at a time which is presumably more than 1 line.